# iis express stop after start debugging in vs 12 and vs13

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web, iis-express

I have a  web application and it worked fine 2 days ago but now it doesn't work  and all other applications in `vs` have same problem,following are the logs:

> 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)):
>   Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)):
>   Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)):
>   Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)):
>   Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)):
>   Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)):
>   Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)):
>   Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Caching\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.Caching.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)):
>   Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)):
>   Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.JScript\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.JScript.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)):
>   Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader\v4.0_1.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader.dll' 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll'
>   'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll'
>   'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime\v4.0_1.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.dll'
>   'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll'
>   The program '[5748] iisexpress.exe: Program Trace' has exited with
>   code 0 (0x0). The program '[5748] iisexpress.exe: Managed
>   (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access
>   violation'.